# WPF Custom Control not showing in Blend Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

New to Custom Control in WPF, I can't figure out why it is not showing in Expression Blend but showing fine at runtime.

I'm trying to use a CustomControl inside a usercontrol.

I do have this in my AssemblyInfo.cs (as suggested in other post)

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page,
// or application resource dictionaries)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page,
// app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

and this :

```
public class ColorPicker : Control
{
    static ColorPicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker)));
    }
```

I tested with a fresh WPF project, loading the custom control is working correctly, I can see it in Expression Blend. But the same doesn't work with my current usercontrol project...

I guess the Generic.xaml from the Custom Control is not loaded correctly but can't find any way to fix that problem.

Comment: Could you post the file tree of your project?

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure I understand. What file tree are you asking for ? please let me know and I'll do it (I'm still beginner)

Comment: The custom control project Tree, (The Solution Tree), like this image: http://tekslate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1024.png

Comment: here : https://snag.gy/Qwvhmd.jpg

Comment: Test if it is loaded in the VS Designer or No.

Comment: how can I test that ? I guess it's not loaded, that's why I can see my custom control, but only at runtime everything is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118746/discussion-between-henka-programmer-and-lecloneur).